# Add css class to html element using php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a problem with why this code is not working.

```
<li><?php if( get_the_archive_title() == "1 Bedroom House Plan") { echo 'class="active-tag"'; } ?><a  href="#">1</a></li>
```

All I want is if the archive page title is equal to the string on the right to echo the CSS class of "active-tag", I'm using WordPress here!

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

you just misplaced your php code :

```
<li> <?php if( get_the_archive_title() == "1 Bedroom House Plan") { echo 'class="active-tag"'; } ?>  <a  href="#">1</a></li>
```

to

```
<li <?php if( get_the_archive_title() == "1 Bedroom House Plan") { echo 'class="active-tag"'; } ?>  
 >
    <a  href="#">1</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've edited the code `<li><a <?php if( get_the_archive_title() == "1 Bedroom House Plan") { echo 'class="active-tag"'; } ?> href="#">1</a></li>` but still not showing the css class

Answer (score 0):

Try to add like below:

```
<li <?php if( get_the_archive_title() == "1 Bedroom House Plan") { echo 'class="active-tag"'; } ?>><a  href="#">1</a></li>
```

Comment: after editing the code to `<li><a <?php if( get_the_archive_title() == "1 Bedroom House Plan") { echo 'class="active-tag"'; } ?> href="#">1</a></li>` still not showing the css class

Answer (score 0):

Few changes and it worked,

`<li><a <?php if( single_cat_title( '', false ) == "1 Bedroom House Plan") { echo 'class="active-tag"'; } ?> href="#">1</a></li>`

Cheers all :)